# Transform with transition twitches in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I have next code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tgh5h70r/1/)

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="image" style="background-image: url(http://loremflickr.com/800/800)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.wrap {
    width: 500px;
}

.item {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    backround-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    transition: all .4s ease;
}

.item:hover .image {
    transform: scale(1.1)
}
</style>
```

If you will put mouse on photo, then leave, then put, then leave once again not very fast (waiting while transition finished), sometimes image is twitches. Looks like trnasition sometimes not working.

Does anybody knows, what is the problem of it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax in your code error:

```
backround-size: cover;
----^
```

this causes a positioning twitches